# Parsing a list to http.get but getting Unsupported Media Type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, httpclient

I am trying to parse in a list of strings from angular to C# but it is giving me a Unsupported Media Type. Usually I have no difficulty with string types but with other objects it doens't work. I am now thinking about making an object that will contain the string and list but am not sure if that is the best way to go about this.

```
public GetIncomplete(companyId: number, locationCodes: string[]) {
let params = httpParam.append('locationCodes', JSON.stringify(locationCodes));

return this.http.get<IvwStockTransfers>(`${this.URL}/get-incomplete?companyId=${companyId}`, {
  params
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove it from the input and add

```
  List<string> locationCodes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(HttpContext.Request.Query["locationCodes"]);
```